# Cannot type in screen session after C-a

Tags: centos, gnu-screen

Often when detaching from a gnu screen, using the ctrl-a+d command, I accidentally don't click the d (simply pressing **ctrl-a**), which prevents any kind of input or commands afterwards. Typing does not give feedback, and it almost feels like the screen is locked. Is there any way to regain access to type in the screen session again after this is done? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are in the command mode. One of ways to quit: press `esc` then `esc`.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. No feedback is given and I am still unable to input anything.